# How to keep override even after unlinking?

Tags: materials, linked-data, library-overrides

I have an object from another Blender file linked into my scene
and I've overridden the default material `Green Material` to `Blue Material`

[image]

but when I unlink the object and relink it again the material gets set back to the default `Green Material`

Is there any method/feature which will allow me to keep the override material change even after unlinking and relinking again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution

https://devtalk.blender.org/t/store-variable-within-blender-scene/5070

store the values within blender itself and then upon linking set those values